# WPF Converter with triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, converters

i have this XAML that looks to see if a row can be 
enabled or not inside a DataGrid

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The converter is working and returns false or true, however when it sends back false, the row is still enabled, have I done anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `IsEnabled` is true. So it will always be true unless you specify in a trigger for it to be `false`.
You should do the following:

```
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Therefore, it'll stay true by default and switch to false only when this trigger is activated.

Comment: Yep, I only saw that mistake when I posted it on here... I apologise. I will mark your answer as correct but it's worth deleting. I don't know. CHeers (Will mark in 10)